# TabControl перетаскивание вкладок

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Добрый день, не могу найти пример возможности организации перетаскивания вкладок в TabControl по типу любого браузера да и самой VisualStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с [Mick Dohertys' .net Tips and Tricks - Tips / TabControl](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm#tip7):

```
// в InitializeComponent():
TabDragger DragTabs = new TabDragger(this.tabControl1, TabDragBehavior.TabDragOut);

// класс для драга
internal class TabDragger
{
    public TabDragger(TabControl tabControl)
        : base()
    {
        this.tabControl = tabControl;
        tabControl.MouseDown +=new MouseEventHandler(tabControl_MouseDown);
        tabControl.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tabControl_MouseMove);
        tabControl.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(tabControl_DoubleClick);
    }

    public TabDragger(TabControl tabControl, TabDragBehavior behavior) 
        : this(tabControl)
    {
        this.dragBehavior = behavior;
    }

    private TabControl tabControl;
    private TabPage dragTab = null;
    private TabDragBehavior dragBehavior = TabDragBehavior.TabDragArrange;

    private TabDragBehavior DragBehavior
    {
        get
        {
            if (!tabControl.Multiline)
                return dragBehavior;
            return TabDragBehavior.None;
        }
    }

    private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragTab = TabUnderMouse();
    }

    private void tabControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DragBehavior == TabDragBehavior.None)
            return;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (dragTab != null)
            {
                if (tabControl.TabPages.Contains(dragTab))
                {
                    if (PointInTabStrip(e.Location))
                    {
                        TabPage hotTab = TabUnderMouse();
                        if (hotTab != dragTab && hotTab != null)
                        {
                            int id1 = tabControl.TabPages.IndexOf(dragTab);
                            int id2 = tabControl.TabPages.IndexOf(hotTab);
                            if (id1 > id2)
                            {
                                for (int id = id2; id <= id1; id++)
                                {
                                    SwapTabPages(id1, id);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for (int id = id2; id > id1; id--)
                                {
                                    SwapTabPages(id1, id);
                                }
                            }
                            tabControl.SelectedTab = dragTab;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.dragBehavior == TabDragBehavior.TabDragOut)
                        {
                            if (dragTab.Tag != null)
                            {
                                ((TabForm)dragTab.Tag).Dispose();
                                dragTab.Tag = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TabForm frm = new TabForm(dragTab);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void tabControl_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DragBehavior == TabDragBehavior.TabDragOut)
        {
            TabForm frm = new TabForm(dragTab);
        }
    }

    #region Private Methods

    private TabPage TabUnderMouse()
    {
        NativeMethods.TCHITTESTINFO HTI = new NativeMethods.TCHITTESTINFO(tabControl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        int tabID = NativeMethods.SendMessage(tabControl.Handle, NativeMethods.TCM_HITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, ref HTI);
        return tabID == -1 ? null : tabControl.TabPages[tabID];
    }

    private bool PointInTabStrip(Point point)
    {
        Rectangle tabBounds = Rectangle.Empty;
        Rectangle displayRC = tabControl.DisplayRectangle; ;

        switch (tabControl.Alignment)
        {
            case TabAlignment.Bottom:
                tabBounds.Location = new Point(0, displayRC.Bottom);
                tabBounds.Size = new Size(tabControl.Width, tabControl.Height - displayRC.Height);
                break;

            case TabAlignment.Left:
                tabBounds.Size = new Size(displayRC.Left, tabControl.Height);
                break;

            case TabAlignment.Right:
                tabBounds.Location = new Point(displayRC.Right, 0);
                tabBounds.Size = new Size(tabControl.Width - displayRC.Width, tabControl.Height);
                break;

            default:
                tabBounds.Size = new Size(tabControl.Width, displayRC.Top);
                break;
        }
        tabBounds.Inflate(-3, -3);
        return tabBounds.Contains(point);
    }

    private void SwapTabPages(int index1, int index2)
    {
        if ((index1 | index2) != -1)
        {
            TabPage tab1 = tabControl.TabPages[index1];
            TabPage tab2 = tabControl.TabPages[index2];
            tabControl.TabPages[index1] = tab2;
            tabControl.TabPages[index2] = tab1;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}

internal class TabForm : Form
{
    public TabForm(TabPage tabPage)
        : base()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.tabPage = tabPage;
        tabPage.Tag = this;
        this.tabControl = (TabControl)tabPage.Parent;
        this.tabID = tabControl.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage);
        this.ClientSize = tabPage.Size;
        this.Location = tabControl.PointToScreen(new Point(tabPage.Left, tabControl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y - SystemInformation.ToolWindowCaptionHeight / 2));
        this.Text = tabPage.Text;
        UnDockFromTab();
        this.dragOffset = tabControl.PointToScreen(Cursor.Position);
        this.dragOffset.X -= this.Location.X ;
        this.dragOffset.Y -= this.Location.Y;
    }

    private TabPage tabPage;
    private TabControl tabControl;
    private int tabID;
    private Point dragOffset;

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        DockToTab();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_MOVING)
        {
            NativeMethods.RECT rc = (NativeMethods.RECT)m.GetLParam(typeof(NativeMethods.RECT));
            Point pt = tabControl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            Rectangle pageRect = tabControl.DisplayRectangle;
            Rectangle tabsRect = Rectangle.Empty;
            switch (tabControl.Alignment)
            {
                case TabAlignment.Left:
                    tabsRect.Size = new Size(pageRect.Left, tabControl.Height);
                    break;

                case TabAlignment.Bottom:
                    tabsRect.Location = new Point(0, pageRect.Bottom);
                    tabsRect.Size = new Size(tabControl.Width, tabControl.Bottom - pageRect.Bottom);
                    break;

                case TabAlignment.Right:
                    tabsRect.Location = new Point(pageRect.Right, 0);
                    tabsRect.Size = new Size(tabControl.Right - pageRect.Right, tabControl.Height);
                    break;

                default:
                    tabsRect.Size = new Size(tabControl.Width, pageRect.Top);
                    break;

            }
            if (tabsRect.Contains(pt))
                DockToTab();
            else
                UnDockFromTab();
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case NativeMethods.WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK:
                this.Close();
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
                if (!this.Visible)
                    this.Close();
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
                {
                    if (!captured)
                    {
                        Point pt = tabControl.PointToScreen((Cursor.Position));
                        Point newPosition = new Point(pt.X - dragOffset.X, pt.Y - dragOffset.Y);
                        this.Location = newPosition;
                    }
                    NativeMethods.RECT rc = new NativeMethods.RECT(this.Bounds);
                    IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rc));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, lParam, true);
                    NativeMethods.SendMessage(this.Handle, NativeMethods.WM_MOVING, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lParam);
                }
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_SETCURSOR:
                captured = true;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    private bool captured;

    private void DockToTab()
    {
        if (!tabControl.TabPages.Contains(tabPage))
        {
            for (int id = this.Controls.Count - 1; id >= 0; id--)
            {
                tabPage.Controls.Add(this.Controls[0]);
            }
            tabControl.TabPages.Insert(tabID, tabPage);
            tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;

            tabControl.Capture = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void UnDockFromTab()
    {
        if (this.Visible || this.IsDisposed)
            return;
        for (int id = tabPage.Controls.Count - 1; id >= 0; id--)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(tabPage.Controls[0]);
        }

        tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
        this.Capture = true;
        this.Show();
    }

}

internal sealed class NativeMethods
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        public RECT(Rectangle bounds)
        {
            this.Left = bounds.Left;
            this.Top = bounds.Top;
            this.Right = bounds.Right;
            this.Bottom = bounds.Bottom;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
        }
    }

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0xA3;

    public const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;

    public const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;

    public const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;
    public const int WM_MOVING = 0x216;
    public const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x232;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, ref TCHITTESTINFO lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TCHITTESTINFO
    {
        public Point pt;
        public TCHITTESTFLAGS flags;
        public TCHITTESTINFO(Point point)
        {
            pt = point;
            flags = TCHITTESTFLAGS.TCHT_ONITEM;
        }
    }

    [Flags()]
    public enum TCHITTESTFLAGS
    {
        TCHT_NOWHERE = 1,
        TCHT_ONITEMICON = 2,
        TCHT_ONITEMLABEL = 4,
        TCHT_ONITEM = TCHT_ONITEMICON | TCHT_ONITEMLABEL
    }

    public const int TCM_HITTEST = 0x130D;

}

public enum TabDragBehavior
{None, TabDragArrange, TabDragOut }
```

Еще две реализации:

- [Reordering TabPages inside TabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/DnDTabControl.aspx)
- [Drag and Drop Tab Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/draggabletabcontrol.aspx)